# VueJS v-on not updating when the function changes

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I'm a newbie with vuejs struggling with an event handler that is not updated.

I have the following `modal` component:

```
  @Options({
    emits: ['main-action']
  })
  export default class Modal extends Vue {
    ...
    public mainActionClick(event: MouseEvent): void {
      this.$emit('main-action', event)
    }
  }
```

And here is an exemple of how another class uses this `modal`:

```
@Options({
  template: `
    <modal
      @main-action="mainAction"
    >
      <div v-html="body"></div>
    </modal>
  `,
  components: { Modal },
})
export class Foo extends Vue {
    ...
    this.mainAction = () => { console.log("within mainAction"); console.log(options?.debuggingId) }
    ...
}
```

I'm having a problem where `mainAction` is updated in `Foo`, but the function handling the `main-action` event on `Modal` doesn't change. Other props are updated correctly, but not the handler. Am I correct in assuming that `modal` isn't detecting that its handler for `main-action` changed? What am I missing?

Comment: You're missing a closing bracket in your emits array - `emits: ['main-action',`

Comment: @paddyfields Thanks for noticing. I had shortened the `emits` array for brevity, and forgot to close the brackets. I have amended the question.